# Can't get tab contents to show up using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am still fairly new to jquery so i am doing some practicing, here i am trying to create a navigation that shows content as you click on each tab but my problem here is that the content wont show, i am not sure if its because i am not using correct identifiers or my code is wrong. please help.

This my html code:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">tab4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">tab5</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active" class="tab">
            <p>tab1</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>tab2</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <ptab3</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab4" class= "tab">
            <p>tab4</p>
            <p>tab4</p>
            <p>tab4</p>
            <UL>
                <LI>tab4</LI>
                <LI>tab4</LI>
                <LI>tab4</LI>
                <LI>tab4</LI>
                <LI>tab4</LI>
            </UL>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is style.css:

```
body {
    background-color: #3399FF;

}

#tabs {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.links: after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: '';

}

.links li {
    margin: 0px 5px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;

}

.links a {
    padding:9px 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
    background:#7FB5DA;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:600;
    color:#4c4c4c;
    transition: all linear 0.15s;
}

.links a:hover {
    background: #a7cce5;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li.active  a, li.active a:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #4c4c4c;
}

.tab-content {
    padding: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    background: #fff;
}

.tab {
    display: none;
}

.tab .active {
    display: block;
}
```

this my jquery.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('.links a').click(function(e){
        var attrValue= $(this).attr('href');

        $('#tabs' + attrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
     }); 
});
```

The content won't show

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gddhyoam/

Comment: Could make life easier and use [http://jqueryui.com/tabs/](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) =o

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$('#tabs ' + attrValue).show().siblings().hide();
```

to

```
$(attrValue).show().siblings().hide();
```

You already capture the ID in `attrValue`, so no need to append anything to `#tabs`.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/16qch9qr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#tabs' + attrValue).show().siblings().hide();
```

you reference `'#tabs'`. There is no id tabs, its a class so the selector is `$('.tabs')` but you dont need that anyway. id's are unique so work by themselves as selectors.

```
 $(attrValue).show().siblings().hide();
```

Comment: @Hanet has a fiddle in his post the shows that it does work so maybe issue elsewhere. Any errors in the console?